# Apps script with custom share invite?

Tags: google-apps-script, invite

I'm quite new to Apps Script, so please bear with me. I wrote a script that from a sheet creates a simple folder structure and then adds an editor. Everything works, but how can I edit text in the share invite? Preferably from a variable read from the sheet?

my two lines:

```
masterClientFolder.addFolder(clientFolder);
clientFolder.addEditor(projUser);
```